# Symfony2 {% for entity in entites %} is not working in bootstamp modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, modal-dialog, window, entity

I'm working whit Symfony2 and Bootstrap to create a modal window.

I have a cataloge.html.twig that show a list of films. For each film, I wont to show a button which opens a modal form (specific for each film).

The problem is that the entity film is not corrected passed to the modal window:

Cataloge.html.twig

```
{% for film in films %}

    ...

    <p>{{ film.title }} - {{ film.directorid().getName() }} - {{ film.year }} </p> // Here is working OK                  

   <a data-toggle="modal" class="open-reservationModal btn btn-primary" data-target="#reservationModal">test</a>

   {% block reservationModal %}

        <div class="modal fade" id="reservationModal" tabindex="-1" film="film">  
           <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

// Here is where i have the problem: it's showing the first film of the list but not the selected film
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="bookId">{{ film.title }} - {{ film.year }}  </h4>        
                    </div>


                           ...

{% endfor%}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating many modals with the same id. Try generate the id with Twig, such as

```
{% for film in films %}
...
<a data-toggle="modal" class="open-reservationModal btn btn-primary" data-target="#{{film.identificator}}">test</a>
...

 <div class="modal fade" id="{{film.identificator}}" tabindex="-1" film="film">

...

{% endfor%}
```

Where film.identificator is an unique id for each modal. You can use Twig loop for generate ids, such as

```
id="algo{{ loop.index }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With your idea I have result the problem: I can pass the id parameter correctly to the modal window, and with that I can acces to the object properties. But now the problem it0s that the form just appear in the first film of the catalog. At the other films the title of the film is the correct one, but the form just don't appear. Any ideas? thanks a lot!!

Comment: Giancarlo, I didn't know how but I have resolve that last problem! Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you have the solution, consider close the question clicking the check in your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. What you mean the check? The vote up? I have already tried but I have not enough 'reputation' here to vote ;)

Comment: No. Under the reputation down arrow, you will see an check when the mouse moves over. You can click on it

Answer (score 0):

Finally runs with this code:

```
{% for film in films %}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{film.id}}" >Reservation</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id={{film.id}}>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">

           {% block modalReservationForm %}

                  {{ render(path('FilmotecaFilmoBundle_reservationform', { 'id' : film.id })) }}

           {%endblock%} 

         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div><!-- /.modal -->    

 {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the support!!